Write mp3 stream to a valid wav file
In my code I'm sending a request to a text-to-speech API and receiving a stream of data that represents audio chunks in mp3 format. I write the data to a mp3 file and it works perfectly:
def textToSpeech(text):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
    url = "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/pNInz6obpgDQGcFmaJgB"
    headers = {
        "Accept": "audio/mpeg",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "xi-api-key": "mykey",
    }
    data = {
        "text": text,
        "model_id": "eleven_multilingual_v2",
        "voice_settings": {"stability": 0.5, "similarity_boost": 0.75},
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open("original/test.mp3", "wb") as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
    return response.status_code

I want to write the data to a wav file and not mp3 file. I know I can convert that file to wav easily but I want to save I/O operations as I'm calling this function alot.
Simply opening wav file and writing to it will result in a corrupted file.
Another way is to use the wave library to open wav file and write the stream to it:
with wave.open("original/test.wav", "wb") as f:
    f.setnchannels(1)
    f.setsampwidth(2)
    f.setframerate(44100)
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE):
        if chunk:
            audio_data = AudioSegment.from_mp3(io.BytesIO(chunk))
            f.writeframes(audio_data.raw_data)

But the result isn't in a good quality as I expected (incomplete and incontinuous), although the values of number of channels, sampling width and framerate are the right values that is expected from the response.

what is different about the quality of the wav file?

@GordonChilds The audio is incomplete and incontinuous
